# Kivy ScreenManager without .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

i'm trying to make a screen transition without a .kv file. Is it possible to do it like this without .kv? Here is the code

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class testW(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(testW, self).__init__()

class emotionRecog(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(emotionRecog, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.button1 = Button(text="Next", size_hint=(1, .1))
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.screenTransition())
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        layout.add_widget(self.button1)
        return layout

    def screenTransition(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'test'


class CamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(emotionRecog(name='emotion'))
        sm.add_widget(testW(name='test'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CamApp().run()
```

After running it i get these error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Study\KivyMultiScreen\main.py", line 53, in <module>
     CamApp().run()
   File "C:\Study\KivyMultiScreen\main.py", line 47, in build
     sm.add_widget(emotionRecog(name='emotion'))
   File "C:\Study\KivyMultiScreen\main.py", line 35, in __init__
     self.button1.bind(on_press=self.screenTransition())
   File "C:\Study\KivyMultiScreen\main.py", line 41, in screenTransition
     self.manager.current = 'test'
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to bind the callback itself to the `on_press` action. This way, Kivy can call that function later.

Change

```
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.screenTransition())
```

to

```
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.screenTransition)
```

The reason your script raised that specific error is because `Screen.manager` is not yet set at the point you called `self.screenTransition` in that line.

You can also check out the first several examples in the [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html?highlight=button%20bind).